# php bitwise flag detection operation

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

// Hi, I want to exclude a flag with bitwise operations, but I don't know how :
// Here are the flags (they come from filesystemiterator)

```
define('CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO', 0);
define('CURRENT_AS_SELF', 16);
define('CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME', 32);
define('CURRENT_MODE_MASK', 240);
define('KEY_AS_PATHNAME', 0);
define('KEY_AS_FILENAME', 256);
define('FOLLOW_SYMLINKS', 512);
define('KEY_MODE_MASK', 3840);
define('NEW_CURRENT_AND_KEY', 256);
define('SKIP_DOTS', 4096);
define('UNIX_PATHS', 8192);
```

The user can potentially set any combination of flags.
I need to detect if CURRENT_AS_SELF or CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME was set,
so here is my function so far:

```
function containsPathnameOrSelfFlag($flags) {
    if ($flags & (CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME | CURRENT_AS_SELF)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is a test suite :

```
var_dump(containsPathnameOrSelfFlag(CURRENT_MODE_MASK | CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME)); // true, ok
var_dump(containsPathnameOrSelfFlag(CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO)); // false, ok
var_dump(containsPathnameOrSelfFlag(CURRENT_MODE_MASK | CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO)); // true, but false was expected, because neither CURRENT_AS_SELF nor CURRENT_AS_SELF were set, so my function is wrong
```

Is it possible to use bitwise operators to make the function pass the third case 
( it should return false )
?

The problem I see here is that the CURRENT_MODE_MASK's bit overlap the CURRENT_AS_SELF
and CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME's bits :

```
0000000000010000 : CURRENT_AS_SELF 
0000000000100000 : CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME 
0000000011110000 : CURRENT_MODE_MASK 
0000000100000000 : KEY_AS_FILENAME
0000001000000000 : FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
0000111100000000 : KEY_MODE_MASK
0000000100000000 : NEW_CURRENT_AND_KEY
0001000000000000 : SKIP_DOTS
0010000000000000 : UNIX_PATHS
```

So every time the user add the CURRENT_MODE_MASK to the flags, my function
will think that the CURRENT_AS_SELF and the CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME were set too, though it's not the case.
I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: CURRENT_MODE_MASK does have the CURRENT_AS_SELF and CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME flags set... Change it to `0000000011000000`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but the flags come from the FilesystemIterator class, I cannot change them, but maybe I misunderstood how CURRENT_MODE_MASK works

Comment: You have to check for the flags in a different way. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13265525/956397).

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that `KEY_MODE_MASK` is technically not set to the correct value, since `KEY_MODE_MASK & FOLLOW_SYMLINKS` returns a truthy result, even though `FOLLOW_SYMLINKS` isn't related to any of the key flags. Thus having `$any_key_flag_set = $fsiObj->getFlags() & $fsiObj::KEY_MODE_MASK;` would return a false positive. `KEY_MODE_MASK` ought to be 3328 (removing 512 from its mask), or `FOLLOW_SYMLINKS` should be 16384 to get it out of the 3840 mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Masks are meant to be anded against the current value for testing, not ored with new values for generation. If you want to test for presence of or use only a single flag, then use only that flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
"Masks are meant to be anded against the current value for testing, not ored with new values for generation."

Do you mean that if a user constructs the FilesystemIterator like this he is wrong ?
$o = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_MODE_MASK);

If so, then my question shouldn't have been posted, and my problem is solved (or at least isn't a real use case)

Comment: Correct. The masks should be used to isolate the specific flags of interest from `getFlags()`, not set the flags for new iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, it was quite hard to find useful information about that flag. The php' docs would just say : Masks FilesystemIterator::current(), which is probably understandable for some people (alas not for me), and the only "doc" I founded was here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11/2011/3/20/8-21, which also made me confuse. Now I think I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `CURRENT_MODE_MASK` to overlap with `CURRENT_AS_SELF` and `CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME` just make sure they don't share a common bit set to 1.
You could set `CURRENT_MODE_MASK` to 64 or 192 to fit the current value, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot change the CURRENT_MODE_MASK's value, it comes from the FilesystemIterator class : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php. I'm not sure to understand how CURRENT_MODE_MASK works though, maybe it shouldn't be use along with CURRENT_AS_SELF and CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME, but no error is thrown when a user set the flags with both CURRENT_MODE_MASK and ( CURRENT_AS_SELF or CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME ) flags.